# What's the simplest way to represent a long string literal with simple pattern in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have a long literal string in Perl, is there a way to represent it as simple pattern without typing it one by one? Such as some syntax as below.

```
$a = "abc" * 2; # $a gets "abcabc";
```

Comment: You might also be interested in related ideas: `perl -E 'say $_ for "a" .. "zz"'` and `perl -E '$l = "a"; say $l++ for 1 .. 10'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [x](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Multiplicative-Operators) operator:

```
$a = "abc" x 2; # $a gets "abcabc";
```